How to control the version of dependency in child modules by parent module
Gradle Version: 8.9
JDK Version: 17
The parent module build.gradle.kt
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.24"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.24"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.6"
}
......
subprojects{
    apply{
        plugin("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    }
    dependencies {
        extra["cloudVersion"] = "2022.0.2"
        extra["alibabaVersion"] = "2022.0.0.0-RC2"
        extra["mybatis-plusVersion"] = "3.5.3.1"
        extra["mysqlVersion"] = "8.0.30"
        extra["knife4jVersion"] = "4.1.0"
        extra["fastjsonVersion"] = "2.0.41"
        extra["vod_apiVersion"] = "2.1.4"
        extra["minioVersion"] = "8.5.2"
        extra["jodatimeVersion"] = "2.10.1"
        extra["xxl-jobVersion"] = "2.4.0"

        extra["wxpayVersion"] = "0.2.11"
        extra["weixinMiniappVersion"] = "4.5.5.B"
        extra["tencentcloudVersion"] = "3.1.322"
        extra["cos_apiVersion"] = "5.6.155"

        extra["redissonVersion"] = "3.23.3"
        extra["commons-ioVersion"] = "2.11.0"

        extra["seataVersion"] = "1.7.1"
        extra["droolsVersion"] = "8.41.0.Final"
        implementation(platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${extra["cloudVersion"]}"))
        implementation(platform("com.alibaba.cloud:spring-cloud-alibaba-dependencies:${extra["alibabaVersion"]}"))

        // mybatis-plus
        implementation("com.baomidou:mybatis-plus-boot-starter:${extra["mybatis-plusVersion"]}")

        // mysql
        implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:${extra["mysqlVersion"]}")

        // knife4j
        implementation("com.github.xiaoymin:knife4j-openapi3-jakarta-spring-boot-starter:${extra["knife4jVersion"]}")
        implementation("com.alibaba:fastjson:${extra["fastjsonVersion"]}")
        implementation("com.qcloud:vod_api:${extra["vod_apiVersion"]}")
        implementation("io.minio:minio:${extra["minioVersion"]}")
        implementation("joda-time:joda-time:${extra["jodatimeVersion"]}")
        implementation("com.xuxueli:xxl-job-core:${extra["xxl-jobVersion"]}")
        implementation("com.github.wechatpay-apiv3:wechatpay-java:${extra["wxpayVersion"]}")
        implementation("org.redisson:redisson:${extra["redissonVersion"]}")
        implementation("com.github.binarywang:weixin-java-miniapp:${extra["weixinMiniappVersion"]}")
        implementation("com.tencentcloudapi:tencentcloud-sdk-java:${extra["tencentcloudVersion"]}")
        implementation("com.qcloud:cos_api:${extra["cos_apiVersion"]}")
        implementation("commons-io:commons-io:${extra["commons-ioVersion"]}")
        implementation("io.seata:seata-all:${extra["seataVersion"]}")
        implementation("org.drools:drools-core:${extra["droolsVersion"]}")
        implementation("org.drools:drools-compiler:${extra["droolsVersion"]}")
        implementation("org.drools:drools-decisiontables:${extra["droolsVersion"]}")
        implementation("org.drools:drools-mvel:${extra["droolsVersion"]}")

When I built one child module, it told me that some the version of dependencies isn't exist.
I just want make parent module to be a tool to control dependencies in every child module.
How can I do to fix the error and make it?
when I add id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.5" to the plugins in parent module build.gradle.tk.
> Error while evaluating property 'mainClass' of task ':bootJar'.
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':bootJar' property 'mainClass'.
      > Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved


Version management becomes much easier when using a version catalog. Can you explain why you don't use one?

If you add the plugin it will be automatically applied, which I doubt you want as probably not every subproject is an actual Spring Boot project (one containing a main class). Add apply false to your plugin. That way you can configure it for a version and it won't be automatically be applied, you can then add the plugin (without version) to projects that actually need it.
